# How to preview my site in AEM 6.0?

Tags: aem

I just started to get my head around AEM 6.0 . Installed an app with 'mvn clean install -Pauto-dev-deploy'. I can see the app in CRXDE and the packages are visible in the packagemanager. It does not however show up in the touchUI. Is it possible to run a preview of this site and how to do it?

Comment: do you have any demo content in the /content section ?
if not you should create some - then your app will be visible in touch ui sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Adobe Experience Manager your application (app) and your content are to different things. Your application contains templates and components with which you build your content.

Deploying your app therefore means that you don't necessarily will have content. Without having a look at your source it is hard to see how and where you can create content. Usually your apps templates and components only work in certain *content paths*. This is usually defined in `/etc/designs/<your-project-name>`

If you are running AEM 6.2 I suggest that you have a look at the new *We Retail* demo application and demo content. The source of which can be found on Github: https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-sample-we-retail

Comment: do you know where I can download a trial version of AEM 6 ?

Comment: @bierhier As far as I know there are no trial versions. Usually you get access to the binaries from Adobe if you have a license.

Comment: Do you know whether I can use angular 2 in combination with aem?

Comment: That depends. We have done projects with Angular and AEM. But we are going off topic. Please search stackoverflow to find out if someone already asked that question. If you don't find one create a new one.

Was your original question answered?